# C asterisks printing pyramind

Tags: c

```
void drawTriangle(int size){
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= size - i; j++){
            printf("  ");
        }
        while(k != 2*i-1){
            printf("* ");
            k++;
        }
        k = 0;
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
int main(void){
    drawTriangle(5);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output:

```
        *
      * * *
    * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
```

the output I was expecting to get was:

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

What am I doing wrong? It is based on the width, not the rows. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `printf("* ");` does?

Comment: In addition to the above comment: The argument to your function gives the number of rows. If it's 5, you're going to get a pyramid of 5 layers.

Comment: well, to start with `for(int j = 1; j <= size - i; j++){ printf("  ");}` prints four `space` s

Comment: Let me guess. You copied the above code from some site but it doesn't do exactly what you need, so you want someone to fix it for you.

Comment: While the question is more or less straightforward, and the answer provided so far is correct, this indeed looks like a copypasta for a homework assignment left to the last minute. I find it hard to believe one could have written the code provided and not know how to fix the above problem.

Comment: Break down the function into smaller tasks: drawTriangleRow(), drawNSpaces(), drawNAsterisks().

Comment: @interjay ya ma niggah. Finding easy way out niggah

Answer (score 0):

Just change these two printf statements:

```
printf("  ");
//...   ^^ Note 2 spaces
printf("* ");
```

to this:

```
printf(" ");
//...
printf("*");
```

And change your function call to this:

```
drawTriangle(3);
           //^ If you want 3 layers and not 5
```

Comment: It is based on the width. Not the number of rows.

Comment: @user4511988 No it's not, just try it out and you will see it!

Comment: drawTriangle(3) do work. However, I am talking about the width base.

Comment: @user4511988 if you want it to define the with and not the layers you would have to rewrite your code logic, if it is your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want your function `drawTriangle(int size)` to draw a base of `size` asterisks.

If so, then you should change how the whole loops work. Your function should stop once it has printed `size` asterisks on a single line, and not when you have printed `size` lines.

Also, as mentioned in comments and other answers, if you want the output to look exactly like the one you put, then you should remove the trailing space in `printf("* ");`.